# Objective C syntax for message passing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying following task:

I know we can calla method on button click by using:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(performModalActionForButton)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Method is like :

```
(void) performModalActionForButton:(NSString *)str
{

}
```

I want to send a string on button click to one method. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two small mistakes in your code..

1. if you use `@selector` and want to choose a function with a parameter you have do add a : ... so it is `@selector(performModalActionForButton:)`
2. the object passed to the function always the sender of the message .. so the function would be:

   ```
   - (void) performModalActionForButton:(UIButton *)button
   {


   }
   ```

In the function you can check the text on the button then... or the tag or whatever you want.

Comment: Regarding (1), note that Objective-C treats the colons as part of the method name, so `@selector(foo)` and `@selector(foo:)` name two different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have the button click trigger an action method that then sends the message whose argument is the string you want to send:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(performModalActionForButton:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction)performModalActionForButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *string = /* get the string you want to send */;
    [obj doSomethingWithString:string];
}
```

Comment: "/* get the string you want to send */" yeah that is the hard part

Comment: The question did not indicate the problem was locating the string, but instead asked about how to pass a given string into a method on button click: "I want to send a string on button click to one method. How can I achieve this?" I took a string as given, and answered how to have a button click trigger passing that given string into a method. GIGO